# How to move uploaded files to public folder inside the public_html in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel website up and running but I am facing the file uploading issue.I am using the move function to move my uploaded files to my public folder. It is working fine in my Xampp but as I uploaded the website to my server it is not working anymore because the public folder is now inside the public_html.
Any help with that??

Comment: Why are you using the `move` function? Laravel has amazing [file storage functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem) which you should be using instead.

Comment: can you help me how can I point my public folder which is inside the public_html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destination where you want to move you file

```
 $destinationPath = 'img';
```

Image new name

```
$imageName = 'img_' . rand(1000000, 9999999) . '.' . $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalExtension(); //$product->id . '.' .$request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Move file

```
$request->file('file_name')->move($destinationPath, $imageName);
```

File path

```
$path = public_path() . '/' . $destinationPath . '/' . $imageName;
```

Comment: My laravel files folder is on the same level as the public_html folder is. 
I want to move the files the user uploads inside the public_html/img folder.

Comment: Where is your laravel index.php file. Is it inside same dir public_html/index.php?